# Google Sheets - Convert entire column of prices by 50%

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, worksheet-function, regexextract

I have a large column of prices, however, sometimes the word `[FIXED]` also appears in these columns (see screenshot below).

I need to convert this price list to wholesale. All the products wholesale prices are exactly 50% of the retail price. I recently discovered more advanced features in google sheets - even playing with some scripts to accomplish more hefty tasks like this one.

Another issue I have is some prices have a .99 for example: 59.99 retail. The wholesale price for this would be 30.00 however.

Is there something I can do to convert all the prices in a specific column by half? 50% of the original value?

Any help would be much appreciated. I know basic js.

[image]

Comment: You basically would use `=MID()` or `=SUBSTITUTE()` to narrow every item down to a numeric value since your text is always the same. Then simply apply your 50% formula and add the text back if desired.

Comment: 50% is a pretty big mark up on clothes by the way!

Comment: Good thing we arent selling clothes. xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the below formula in cell B2 and copy it to all other cells.

```
=if(A2="", "",  iferror(left(A2, find("]", A2)), "") & round(right(A2, len(A2) - iferror(find("]", A2), 0)), 0)/2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "\[FIXED\]"))&
 TEXT(ROUND(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(A2:A), "\d+.\d+|\d+")*1-
 (REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(A2:A), "\d+.\d+|\d+")*1)*50%, 2),"#.00")))
```

[image: 0]